# How to check if user is following the other one before following or unfollowing (attach)

Tags: mysql, if-statement, laravel-5.4

I used many to many relationship in my user table to make the logged in user to follow another one, but I didn't figuerd it out by myself, I checked what others did and tried to do something similar and it worked. In my methods I have:

```
function follow(User $user) {
    $this->followers()->attach($user->id);
}

function unfollow(User $user) {
    $this->followers()->detach($user->id);
}
```

which allows me follow.

the tables are related with a function something like:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
```

now I pass the `$user` value by the controller and the controller is pretty simple:

```
    $userId = User::find($user);
    $willfollow = Auth::user();

    $willfollow->unfollow($userId);
```

I know the controller information is probably not needed but in case it is easy to check the relation within the controller I would prefer to do it that way, because I'm obviously don't have that much knowledge of method use.

I am using Laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Laravel 5.3 you can use syncWithoutDetaching (**the most efficient**):

```
$this->followers()->syncWithoutDetaching([$user->id]);
```

Other ways:

```
$this->followers()->sync([$user->id], false);
```

Check for existing before save (efficient only if you have already loaded `$this->followers`):

```
function follow(User $user) {
    if(!$this->followers->contains($user)) {
        $this->followers()->attach($user->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for these opinions, it feels lile contains will get all followers from database and see if any one is matching. Is there a more optimised way possible?

Comment: @Nikonah the last example `syncWithoutDetaching` is the most efficient Laravel/Eloquent way of doing it

Comment: @andrewtweber BTW I forgat to mention, do you know how I can get the count of followers? or am I supposed to store it in database too

Comment: @Nikonah `$this->followers()->count()`. The parentheses after `followers` is important. If you try `$this->followers->count()` without parentheses then it will fetch all of the follower objects, which is inefficient. If you use the parentheses then it will run a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query which is much more efficient.